# LDAP Authentication in SpringBoot not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-ldap

Below is my spring security ldap authentication code snippet
I am able to authenticate admin user as shown in CASE 2. However, when I am not able to authenticate user1 as shown in CASE 1 for a different base dn.

```
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        if (ldapEnabled) {
            auth.ldapAuthentication()
                    .userDetailsContextMapper(customContextMapper())
                    .userSearchFilter("(&(objectClass=user)(" + userDn+ "))")
                    .contextSource()
                    .url(ldapProviderUrl + baseDn.trim().replaceAll(" ", "%20"))
                    .managerDn(ldap.username)
                    .managerPassword(ldap.password);
        } else {
            super.configure(auth);
        }
    }
```

The properties that I use are
For case 1

```
ldap.enabled=true
ldap.provider.url=ldap://XX.XX.XX.XX:389/
ldap.username=CN=XXXXXX,OU=**People**,DC=pserv,DC=local
ldap.password=#########
ldap.base.dn=OU=**User Accounts**,DC=pserv,DC=local
ldap.user.dn.patterns=sAMAccountName={0}
ldap.user.password.attribute=userPassword
ldap.search.base.group=ou=groups
```

for case 2

```
ldap.enabled=true
ldap.provider.url=ldap://XX.XX.XX.XX:389/
ldap.username=CN=XXXXXX,OU=**People**,DC=pserv,DC=local
ldap.password=#########
ldap.base.dn=OU=**People**,DC=pserv,DC=local
ldap.user.dn.patterns=sAMAccountName={0}
ldap.user.password.attribute=userPassword
ldap.search.base.group=ou=groups
```

And my ldap directory tree: (Failed case) CASE 1 :

[image]

Working Ldap directory CASE 2:

[image]

Questions:

1. Is it because my ldap.username OU is under "**People**"?
2. I fixed the issue for space in the base dn in case 1 nu replacing with %20. But I am not able to authenticate the user. Getting this error

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-03100245, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
    'DC=pserv,DC=local'
 ]; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-03100245, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
    'DC=pserv,DC=local'
 ]; remaining name '/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is with spring-security not able to handle basedn with space.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/2264

Replacing the space in the basedn with %20 helps in successfully building the application. However, the workaround provided above doesn't work for me.